# What is actually happens when moving a file onto/into another file?

Tags: macos, command-line, filesystem, data-recovery, data

I was trying to move some files to a directory, because of wrong destination directory path all files are moved to another **file**.

*Can I undo this action to get my files back? - **Hopefully NO***

Is there any way to **typecast the destination file to a folder/directory**? What is actually happening behind the scene when we do like this?

**Update**

Command used:

```
mv MyFile.extention /MyFolder
```

Comment: Do you have a backup? As for "typecasting" I believe the `-i` option in `mv` prompts the user before overwriting existing files.

Comment: No I don't have the backup of the files I moved. And I didn't used `-i` option while doing `mv` command.

Comment: I don't believe there is an easy way to recover files lost in this manner. If you don't have a backup, it's another "how do I recover deleted files" question. There should be some here on Ask Different, look through them.

Comment: I didn't deleted them, I have a file into which I move other files. So I think its not about "how do I recover deleted files". 

sorry, ` Ask Different` I didn't get this? what is this?

Comment: Ask Different is the name of this Q&A site, in really big letters at the top left... :| Could you post the command you used? That would be really helpful. Please [edit] your post to include the command, don't comment it. And select it and press Ctrl+K to format it as code.

Comment: Technically speaking, overwriting a file by moving another one "onto it" is the same as deleting it. So if you don't have a backup, you'll probably be out of luck.

Comment: @patrix  Thanks. :) 
As for the more clarification on that `Technical` section am going to update whole question itself.

Comment: mv MyFile.extention /MyFolder - this is a standard Unix command and will replace a MyFile.extention in MyFolder if such a file already exists. There is no way to recover from running such a command.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize the answers in the comments:

Moving a file using `mv` writes/moves the source file to the destination path. If you put an existing file as the destination *without using* the `-i` flag the existing file will be overwritten.

This is the same as deleting it.

Recommendation/possible ways to avoid this in the future:

- Keep a backup, especially of important files
- Always use the `-i` flag when using `mv` to be prompted before overwriting existing files
- Use the Finder to move files to avoid mistakes via the command line